# Cubic root is not showing accurately

Tags: fonts, unicode-math, indic

Following up this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/622610/243840), I have added this code:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{babel}
\babelprovide[import, onchar = fonts ids]{bengali}
\babelfont[bengali]{rm}[Renderer=Harfbuzz,AutoFakeBold,AutoFakeSlant=0.3]{Kalpurush}
\babelcharproperty{`।}{locale}{bengali}

\babelprovide[maparabic,alph=alphabetic]{bengali}

%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

%--------------- Problematic code starts
\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}
\setmathfont{fontkalpurush.ttf}[range={"0980-"09FF}]
\newcount\tmpcount
% re-do range No idea why this is needed
\AtBeginDocument{
\tmpcount="0980
\loop
\Umathcode\tmpcount 0 4 \tmpcount
\ifnum\tmpcount<"09FF
\advance\tmpcount 1
\repeat
}
%--------------- Problematic code ends

\begin{document} 
text
    ৩৪২

math
    $৩৪^২$ %34^2
\begin{align*}
    ৩৪২ &= (৩৪+৪)(৩৪-৪) + ৪২\\
    &= ৩৮৩০ + ৪২
\end{align*}
    \[ \sqrt[৩]{\frac{১}{২}} \] 
\end{document}
```

It works fine for that question, but while I write cubic root equation, it doesn't show actual shape. The *Problematic code* is shown here using comment area `%--------------- Problematic code`. How I can get the right shape of cubic root keeping other settings OK?

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need

```
\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}
\setmathfont{fontkalpurush.ttf}[range={"0980-"09FF}]
\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}[range=]
```

That's a known problem with `unicode-math` and ranges.

However, instead of “magic” code that's *not* guaranteed to work because it relies on some number that's not predetermined, I'd assign a math symbol font and forget of the rest.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{babel}
\babelprovide[import, onchar = fonts ids]{bengali}
\babelfont[bengali]{rm}[
  Renderer=Harfbuzz,
  AutoFakeBold,
  AutoFakeSlant=0.3,
  NFSSFamily=kalpurush,
]{fontkalpurush.ttf}
\babelcharproperty{`।}{locale}{bengali}

\babelprovide[maparabic,alph=alphabetic]{bengali}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}

\DeclareSymbolFont{bangla}{\encodingdefault}{kalpurush}{m}{n}
\Umathcode"09E6 = "0 \symbangla "09E6 % 0
\Umathcode"09E7 = "0 \symbangla "09E7 % 1
\Umathcode"09E8 = "0 \symbangla "09E8 % 2
\Umathcode"09E9 = "0 \symbangla "09E9 % 3
\Umathcode"09EA = "0 \symbangla "09EA % 4
\Umathcode"09EB = "0 \symbangla "09EB % 5
\Umathcode"09EC = "0 \symbangla "09EC % 6
\Umathcode"09ED = "0 \symbangla "09ED % 7
\Umathcode"09EE = "0 \symbangla "09EE % 8
\Umathcode"09EF = "0 \symbangla "09EF % 9

\begin{document} 

text
    ৩৪২

math
    $৩৪^২$ %34^2
\begin{align*}
    ৩৪২ &= (৩৪+৪)(৩৪-৪) + ৪২\\
    &= ৩৮৩০ + ৪২
\end{align*}
    \[ \sqrt[৩]{\frac{১}{২}} \] 
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't want to repeat the ten declarations, the code below suffices.

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{bangla}{\encodingdefault}{kalpurush}{m}{n}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_step_inline:nnn { "09E6 } { "09EF } { \Umathcode #1 = "0 \symbangla #1 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Comment: Thanks for your great help.